# Ajax update with SailsJS and MongoDB

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, sails.js

I'm at the beginning of my sailsJS using course.

I've a question concerning how to update my model with MongoDB through a jquery ajax request.
Here's my code :

```
jQuery("a#identity-edit").on("click", function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/character/update',
        method: 'POST',
         data: {
            id: $("a#identity-edit").attr("data-id"),
            name: 'myNewName'
         },
        success: function() {
            window.location('/character/show/'+$("a#identity-edit").attr("data-id"));
        },
        failure: function(msg) {
            alert("Fail : " + msg);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, text) {
            alert(text);
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr, responseText);
            alert(response.error);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, this code is catched by the "error" handler with an empty text...

Could you explain me what's wrong please ?

Thanks by advance,

Cyril

Comment: What is wrong is you likely have a server side error and this is not server code. You need to show that part in your question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. Your question **only** shows your client code, you POST to an endpoint on your server. We need to see what is happening there.

Comment: I understand but I haven't any other code, because I'd like to use the REST API of sails which can CRUD by URL like /:controller/update/:id?parameters ...  The thing I don't understand is if I launch this code, I've an error status, but if I reload the page (with F5), the data is correctly store in mongodb and properly displayed in my page...

Comment: I somehow knew you would say that. Can you hit that REST point with the data you expect. Looks like you're passing in a object to `data` so that **should** be okay. Google "curl JSON" to see how to test.

Answer (score 0):

When POSTing to an API via jQuery, you need to do a little more work to get your data ready:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/character/update',
    method: 'POST',

    // Tell the server we're sending JSON--not strictly necessary with Sails,
    // but recommended.
    contentType: 'application/json', 

    // Don't URLencode data
    processData: false,

    // Stringify the data--otherwise it will send "[object object]"
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: $("a#identity-edit").attr("data-id"),
        name: 'myNewName'
     }),

    success: function() {
        window.location('/character/show/'+$("a#identity-edit").attr("data-id"));
    },
    failure: function(msg) {
        alert("Fail : " + msg);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, text) {
        alert(text);
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr, responseText);
        alert(response.error);
    }
});
```

Also, are you sure you want `POST`?  Updates are done using `PUT` if you're using Sails blueprints.